# Thread 7: EXC_BREAKPOINT error at group.leave() in swift

Tags: ios, swift, breakpoints

I'm encountering an EXC_BREAKPOINT error in my iOS app, specifically at the line group.leave() in the makeAPICallForCategories function. The strange thing is that the value of the error's subcode varies between numbers 7, 3, and 2. I've included the relevant code snippet below.

> 

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  practice
//
//  Created by aycan duskun on 12.03.2023.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore


class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    
    var user: User?
    let titleLabel                      = SPTitleLabel(textAlignment: .left, fontSize: 20)
    let userImage                       = SPImageView(cornerRadius: 40)
    let querySearchBar                  = SPSearchBar()
    var queryRecipesVC: QueryRecipesVC!
    let cancelButton                    = SPButton(backgroundColor: .clear, title: "Cancel")
    var recipes: [(tag: String, recipe: [Recipe])]      = []
    var similarRecipesArray: [GetSimilarRecipes] = []
    let categoryHeaderView              = CategoriesHeaderView()
    let recommendationHeaderTitle       = SPTitleLabel(text: "Recommendation", textAlignment: .left, fontSize: 20)
    
    let recommendationSeeAllButton      = SPButton(backgroundColor: .clear, title: "See All")
    let tags = [Tags.breakfast, Tags.lunch, Tags.dinner, Tags.soup, Tags.dessert]
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    
    private var searchDebounceTimer: Timer?
    
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CategoriesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CategoriesCollectionViewCell.reuseID)
        collectionView.register(RecommendationCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: RecommendationCollectionViewCell.reuseID)
        collectionView.register(CategoriesHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "CategoriesHeader", withReuseIdentifier: CategoriesHeaderView.headerIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(RecommendationHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "RecommendationHeader", withReuseIdentifier: RecommendationHeaderView.headerIdentifier)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
       
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        configureCompositionalLayout()
        getCategoriesFromCache()
        setupQueryRecipesVC()
        layoutUI()
        fetchRecipeData()
        configure()
        createDismissKeyboardTapGesture()
        retrieveUserInfo()
        cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    private func setupQueryRecipesVC() {
        queryRecipesVC = QueryRecipesVC()
        addChild(queryRecipesVC)
        view.addSubview(queryRecipesVC.view)
        queryRecipesVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        queryRecipesVC.view.isHidden = true
        queryRecipesVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        querySearchBar.delegate = self
    }
    
    
    @objc func cancelButtonTapped() {
        queryRecipesVC.view.isHidden = true
        collectionView.isHidden = false
        cancelButton.isHidden = true
        querySearchBar.text = ""
    }

    
    func makeAPICallForCategories(tag: String, atIndex index: Int, group: DispatchGroup) {
        NetworkManager.shared.getRecipesInfo(for: .searchCategory(tag)) { [weak self] category in
            
            guard let self = self else { return }
           
            
            switch category {
            case .success(let categories):
                
                for category in categories {
                    PersistenceManager.updateWith(category: category, actionType: .add) { error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error saving category: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.updateUI(with: categories, atIndex: index)
            case .failure(let error):
                break
            }
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    
    func fetchRecipeData() {
        recipes = tags.map { (tag: $0, recipe: []) }
        
        for (index, tag) in tags.enumerated() {
            group.enter()
            makeAPICallForCategories(tag: tag, atIndex: index, group: self.group)
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    
    func getCategoriesFromCache() {
        // First, try to retrieve categories from cache
        for (index, tag) in tags.enumerated() {
            PersistenceManager.retrievedCategories { [weak self] result in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                
                switch result {
                case .success(let cachedCategories):
                    if !cachedCategories.isEmpty {
                        // If cached categories are available, update UI
                        print("Data is coming from cache: \(cachedCategories)")
                        self.updateUI(with: cachedCategories, atIndex: index)
                    } else {
                        // If not available in cache, make API call
                        print("Data is not available in cache, making API call...")
                        self.makeAPICallForCategories(tag: tag, atIndex: index, group: self.group)
                    }
                    // If there's an error retrieving from cache, make API call
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error retrieving categories from cache: \(error)")
                    }
        
                }
            }
        }
    
    
    
    func configure() {
        collectionView.setUp(to: view, and: querySearchBar)
        cancelButton.isHidden = true
    }
    
    
    func updateUI(with categories: [Recipe], atIndex index: Int) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.recipes[index].recipe = categories
        }
    }
    
    
    func fetchSimilarRecipes(recipeID: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[GetSimilarRecipes], SPError>) -> Void) {
        print("Fetching similar recipes for recipeID: \(recipeID)")
        NetworkManager.shared.getSimilarRecipes(recipeID: recipeID) { result in
            
            //guard let self = self else {return}
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let similarRecipes):
                print("Fetched similar recipes: \(similarRecipes)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(similarRecipes))
                    self.similarRecipesArray.append(contentsOf: similarRecipes)
                    print("SIMILAR RECIPES ARE: \(self.similarRecipesArray)")
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching similar recipes: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                //self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.tableView)
            }
        }
    }
```

This issue started happening after I added a new section under the makeAPICallForCategories function that involves the PersistenceManager. Before adding this section, the code used to work fine without any crashes.

Additionally, I'm using a DispatchGroup named group to ensure that all API calls are completed before reloading the collectionView data.

Any insights into why this error is occurring and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I would look into the forced unwrap of `QueryRecipesVC!` first. Unwrapping nil value is usually the reason for EXC_BREAKPOINT

Comment: Usually, a `group.leave()` causing a crash, is because you've called `leave()` more than `enter()`. In your case, you are calling `leave()` inside `getCategoriesFromCache` where you haven't called `enter()` for each one.

Comment: but QueryRecipesVC has been there for ages and there wasn't this kind of problem. didn't do anything related to it. It just shows up when I search for recipes.

Comment: @Larme should I place a group.enter() inside getCategoriesFromCache as well?

Comment: Your code is strange: First I wouldn't use `group` as an instance var, but as a local var. Also, You check for cache, and if there isn't you make the API call, but later in `viewDidLoad()` you do also the API call...

Comment: you mean fetchRecipeData inside viewDidLoad right?